# Why does the F# Bitwise Operator pad with 1's for signed types?

Tags: c#, c++, f#, history, bit-shift

I was looking at F# doc on bitwise ops:

> **Bitwise right-shift operator**. The
>   result is the first operand with bits
>   shifted right by the number of bits in
>   the second operand. Bits shifted off
>   the least significant position are not
>   rotated into the most significant
>   position. For unsigned types, the most
>   significant bits are padded with
>   zeros. For signed types, the most
>   significant bits are padded with ones.
>   The type of the second argument is
>   int32.

What was the motivation behind this design choice comparing to C++ language (and probably C too) where MSB are padded with zeros? E.g:

```
int mask = -2147483648 >> 1; // C++ code
```

where -2147483648 =

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

and mask is equal to 1073741824

where 1073741824 =

```
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Now if you write same code in F# (or C#), this will indeed pad MSB with ones and you'll get -1073741824.

where -1073741824 =

```
11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: In C and C++, the result of shifting a negative value is not defined in the standard.

Comment: @Oli: Ah I see, so that would be the reason then

Comment: Incidentally, that quote sounds a bit weird.  Surely it should say "for **negative values**, the most significant bits are padded with ones"?

Comment: So my question should be more: why C and C++ didn't defined signed right shifting into the language?

Comment: @Stringer: because C/C++ don't require 2's complement integers.  It's super-annoying that a lot of things are officially undefined behaviour because they'd work differently on 1's complement hardware.  8 bits per byte isn't required by C, either.  In most specific C implementations, right-shifting a signed integer uses an arithmetic shift, shifting in copies of the sign bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thank you, get it now. Really, UB has spread like the plague across C. With LLVM using a two's complement representation for integers, this is our hope that things get in order eventually for new languages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the reformed question (in the comments):

The C and C++ standards do not define the result of right-shifting a negative value (it's either implementation-defined, or undefined, I can't remember which).

This is because the standard was defined to reflect the lowest common denominator in terms of underlying instruction set.  Enforcing a true arithmetic shift, for instance, takes several instructions if the instruction set doesn't contain an `asr` primitive.  This is further complicated by the fact that the standard mandates *either* one's *or* two's complement representation.

Answer (score 7):

The signed shift has the nice property that shifting x right by n corresponds to floor(x/2<sup>n</sup>).

On .NET, there are CIL opcodes for both types of operations (`shr` to do a signed shift and `shr.un` to do an unsigned shift).  F# and C# choose which opcode to use based on the signedness of the type which is being shifted.  This means that if you want the other behavior, you just need to perform a numeric conversion before and after shifting (which actually has no runtime impact due to how numbers are stored on the CLR - an int32 on the stack is indistinguishable from a uint32).

Comment: I don't know what the semantics are on .NET, but in a typical C implementation, there's a sequence of pathological cases where the shift-divide equivalence doesn't hold.  For instance, typically: `(-1 >> 1) != (-1 / 2)`.

Comment: @Oli - Yes, that's true in .NET as well...  I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @Oli, strictly both `-1 >> 1` and `-1 / 2` correctly divide by zero. They do round differently though, the shift doing statistical rounding and the integer division doing primary-school rounding. Still leads to errors where equivalence is assumed, but it is still a shift-divide equivalence.

Comment: Jon, I really doubt you get any operation in any language to "correctly divide by zero"... :)

Comment: Heh. Yes, that was an amusing typo.